Wordpress Theme is not loading child theme stylesheet
I'm having an issue with wordpress where I have two versions of the top menu loading up after a few clicks.  After some investigation I noticed the Child theme style sheet was not loading up after a bit.  I figured this could be a caching issue, so I disabled a few plugins and now I'm trying to force load my child theme in functions.php.
I have the following code trying to force load my stylesheet.
function my_child_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    // Dequeue and deregister any previously enqueued styles with the same handle
    wp_dequeue_style( 'child-style' );
    wp_deregister_style( 'child-style' );
    $parent_style = 'flatsome'; // Replace with the correct handle for the parent theme's stylesheet.

    // Enqueue parent theme stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );

    // Enqueue child theme stylesheet located in the 'assets' directory
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_child_theme_enqueue_styles' );

I'm not quite sure what's going on. If I check the network tab on google chrome then, the parent stylesheet loads up but the child theme style sheet is missing.

If, in your child theme, the stylesheet you want to load is located in the assets directory (as per the comment in your code) then perhaps you need to include this directory in the path?
// Enqueue child theme stylesheet located in the 'assets' directory
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/style.css');

But there may be two problems. If the <link> tag for the child theme is not appearing in the rendered page at all, then most likely a PHP error has occurred and you need to check your error log for details.

Thanks Brett for your answer.  I will definitely check the error logs.   I noticed that the  tag wasn't showing up, so I assumed it was a caching issue.  The site was using Nitropack, and I forced it to omit any operations on my desired stylesheet, and it shows up one hundred percent now.  I'll still check the error logs in case there is anything missing.
